# Is there a way to modify NavigationManager.RoadView zoom behaviour?

Tags: heremaps-android-sdk

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.18/api_reference_java/content/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.html

I am using:

> ROADVIEW -
> Map updated using NavigationManager.RoadView, with zoom level automatically adjusted according to the approaching maneuver, road type and speed.

Can I change the default automatic zoom behaviour? Is there any value multiplier available?

I am using HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition) 3.18.3